# HTML5: element <group>

Tags: javascript, html, w3c, w3c-validation

What valid [[image: HTML5]**HTML5-tag**](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_reference.asp) do you suggest, **to combine one or more elements into a group**?

*Example:*

```
  <!-- Not valid, see below - just ignore -->
    <ul>
      <li>Test1<li>
      <group id="2"><li>Test 2</li></group>
      <li>Test2<li>
      <li>Test3<li>
    </ul>
 <!-- // -->

  <p>Test Text 1 <group id="3">Lorem ipsum dolor</group></p>

</body>
</html>
```

*Javascript (with DOM-Utility):*

```
console.log($('group#2'));
```

Comment: The above would not be valid because `<ul>` elements only allow `<li>` elements as direct children.

Comment: You'Re right, i've corrected my question. I'm looking for a abstract solution, without using class-identificators

Comment: Your edit hasn't made the question more clear, sorry. In what way do the one list element and the piece of text in the p belong together?

Comment: I mean, does HTML5 give us the ability to group parts of elements in a respectful and valid way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the context. [Here is the spec for all grouping elements of block level](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/grouping-content.html#grouping-content) (or I like [this visualization](http://joshduck.com/periodic-table.html)). You want something that fits *semantically*. For example, if you have an article, you'll want to use the `<article>` tag. If you are defining a section of the page, use a `<section>`. If you are grouping headers, use `<hgroup>`. If you are doing x, use x tag.

The list goes on and on and on. Find the appropriate element for the context. But do note, older browsers won't know how to handle the elements, so you'll need to be aware of that in how you style and how you use JavaScript to query the elements.

Comment: And, if you want to group stuff like a `<li>` and a `<p>`, assign them the same class name. Or is there another way?

Comment: @bfavaretto It depends on the _semantic context_. Like I state in my answer. There is no blanket "Use this tag for all `<p>` elements" because HTML5 adds extra semantics to use. Like I say, if it is part of an article, then use `<article>` tag, If it is... on and on and on. It is about what is best _semantically_. Classes are more meant for classifying elements into different classes.

Comment: I know, and I agree, but he seems to be looking for something to group content *across* blocks. For example, you have two `<article>` blocks, each with a different `<span>` inside, which you'd like to group together for some reason (like accessing from js, as in the OP). Then the only way would be to give both spans the same class.

Comment: @bfavaretto The group tags the OP uses have different `id`s and therefore would be different groups. But if they were trying to select them from different block contexts, then yes, a class _might_ be appropriate. However, it might also be appropriate to be in two `<section>` tags and to select it using the `<section>` tag as well. Or some other tag. It is always hard to say without concrete examples.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better, to give the developer the ability to define his own, custom scope of HTML5-tags? One scope for **reserved elements** and another, open scope for custom tags. I take this as a disadvantage of the latest w3c specification. What do you think?

Comment: @msec Oh I **very** much disagree. That is what we have a standard for. To be able to tell the browser how to handle our code. Otherwise, we get IE 5 (not even up to par with IE 6) all over again. They do however allow custom attributes if you lead it with `data-`. This allows you to add data to any element. But no, I don't think we should ever go back to "Use whatever tags make you happy and we'll have to try and figure it out"

Comment: I do agree. But remember, that back in the days of IE5+6 **Javascript** wasn't the language of the browser. The current HTML5 specification depends on a predefined tag scope and makes the playground dry, regarding to the abstract possibilites of Javascript. Next generation of HTML should be more flaccid.

Comment: @msec JScript (their implementation of JavaScript) was introduced in IE 3. Abstract possibilities of JavaScript are anything but dry, as you can see by the movement of HTML5 Games, Animations, etc. Anyway, this is well off topic now. If you'd like to continue this discussion, we can move it to the HTML [chat]

Answer (score 0):

In this situation you should just use a class name:

```
<li class="group2">Test 2</li>
```

Comment: That does give them the same class attribute, yes, but I think by grouping the OP does mean something more like a fieldset around them or something.